# Bootstrap modal popup with ajax using different element and same id

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

im currently working on a newsletter project and stuck in this case.

In the "List" page i show all of the mailing list with the bootstrap datatable and every single record has an "action" icons with it (view,edit,delete). When user hit the **"view" icon** i want to use bootstrap modal popup with another datatable inside it to show the **"email list"** of its record . In order to  retrieve the data inside the modal i use the Ajax function to connect trough the database and i use **"data-row"** attribute in each element to get the id of the row.

Here is my **"list"** page code

```
<table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th style="width:5%;">No</th>
    <th>Nama Milis</th>
    <th style="width:20%;">Jumlah email</th>
    <th>Action</th>

  </tr>
</thead>


<tbody>

<?php 
$i=1;
foreach ($milis as $milis){
?>


  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $i;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $milis['nama'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $this->m_mailinglist->get_mail_milis($milis['id'])->num_rows();?></td>
    <td>
    <button type="button" id="view-button" class="btn btn-success" data-row="<?php echo $milis['id'];?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".email-modal"><i class="fa fa-eye" ></i></button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
    </td>

  </tr>
<?php
$i++;
}
?> 


</tbody>
```

as you can see there is an attribute called **data-row** contains the record's id, **but i only use the same name "view-button" on my record**, is this the problem?

```
<button type="button" id="view-button" class="btn btn-success" data-row="<?php echo $milis['id'];?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".email-modal"><i class="fa fa-eye" ></i></button>
```

and this is my ajax code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#view-button").click(function(e){

      var id = e.target.getAttribute("data-row");
      alert(id);
      $('.loading').show();
      $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        cache:false,
        url:'<?php echo base_url();?>Mailinglist/ajax_listemail',
        data:{id:id},
        success:function(data){
          $('.loading').hide();
          $('.modal-content').html(data);

        },
        async:false
      });


  });

});
```

i use the **get_Attribute** to retrieve the **data-row** attribute of every single element i clicked

the problem is the click function is only work in the first button of the record, the rest of record wont show the "id" alert and the data cannot be retrieved. AlsoAny solutions of this or any simplest way to do this? thank you :)

Comment: Use below code on click button remove modal ..... on click function after getting result this will open modal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).on("click", '.requestmail', function(event) {


var valu   = $(this).attr('attrd');
  alert(valu);
var $modal = $('#myModal');


 $.ajax({
                                    
                                    method: "POST",
                                   
   url: '<?php echo base_url();?>Mailinglist/ajax_listemail',
   cache: false,
   data: {id:valu},
                              success: function(msg)
                              {
                              if(msg!='')
                              {
                              $modal.modal('show');
                             $(".modal-data2").html(msg);
                              
                               }
                        
                              }
                            

 });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button type="button" id="view-button" class="btn btn-success requestmail" attrd="1" ><i class="fa fa-eye" ></i></button>

<button type="button" id="view-button" class="btn btn-success requestmail" attrd="2" ><i class="fa fa-eye" ></i></button>

<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm request-form" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
               <div class="modal-content modal-data2">
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
```

Comment: Thanks ! its working ! , but why the css of the modal is messed? http://imgur.com/a/Fdgyj

Comment: Hi, you can style it according to your requirement

Comment: nevermind, its just a miss class placement heheh, i just changed the  $(".modal-data2").html(msg); to  $(".modal-content").html(msg);

Thank you so much ! :D :D